# How to make Next.js image component fetch smaller image?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import ImageTeam from '../public/images/team.jpeg'

<Image
  src={ImageTeam}
  width={720}
  height={480}                
  sizes="720px"                                
/>
```

The image the code above is fetching is this:

`http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=team.jpg&w=1920&q=75`

The `w=1920`. I would like to make `w=720`. How can I do that? I would like to keep the image statically imported.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the image URL by passing additional options to the next/image component. Specifically, you can set the layout prop to "fixed" and pass the desired width and height values as an object to the width prop. Here's an example

```
import ImageTeam from '../public/images/team.jpeg'

<Image
  src={ImageTeam}
  layout="fixed"
  width={{ width: 720, height: 480 }}
  sizes="720px"                                
/>
```

This will generate an image URL like:

```
http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fteam.jpeg&w=720&q=75
```

Note that the width and height options are passed as an object with width and height properties. Also, setting the layout prop to "fixed" ensures that the image will always be rendered at the specified dimensions, rather than being scaled up or down based on its container.